# Парсинг Excel файла в Android

Tags: android, excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На изображении выше показана одна из ячеек таблицы, которую мне нужно распарсить. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно разделить эти два текста - выше черты и ниже, а также сделать проверку на подобные ячейки. Я юзаю Apache POI библиотеку, которая функционирует на Android! 
Вот тестовый фрагмент кода:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    try {

        AssetManager manager = getAssets();
        InputStream input = manager.open("timetable.xls"); // загрузка xls файла
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input); 

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // получаем первый лист

        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(6).getCell(4); // та самая ячейка

        if (...) { // здесь проверка, если ячейка имеет подобную диагональ

            String leftTopStr = ...; // взять верхний текст над чертой

            String rightBottomStr = ...; // взять нижний текст под чертой




    } catch (IOException exc) {
        Log.d("TEST", exc.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: что вы получаете в ответе ?

Comment: Я получаю строку ввида:  Астрономия  {здесь 6-10 пробелов} Ин.яз.(1 гр.). Я сначала подумал может наличие большего количества пробелов решит мою проблему и я смогу отличить подобные ячейки, но такие ячейки также встречаются в таблице. При получении текста я использовал простейший метод cell.getStringCellValue(); Также я пробовал вызывать getCellStyle для получение подробной информации о стилях ячеек, но не смог разобраться)))